# POST 400 (BAD REQUEST) when uploading file between React & Django Rest Api

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I created a user form that's motive is to add a new user and storing in the database. I have built up a rest API using the `Django rest framework`. But I getting an error is `Users.js:63 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/ 400 (Bad Request)`

Where did the actual problem occur? Give me a solution...

### React

***Users component:***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import UserForm from './UserForm';
const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/";

const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const getAllusers = () => {

        fetch(URL)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw Error("Could not fetch!");
                }
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setUsers(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(err.message);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getAllusers();
    }, []);




const addUSer = (user) => {

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username',user.username);
        formData.append('profileImage',user.profileImage[0]);
        formData.append('email',user.email);

        fetch(URL, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'},
            body: formData
            
        })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status == 201) {
                    getAllusers();
                }else{
                    throw new Error("Could not created User!");
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(err.message);
            });
    }

    return (
        <section className='container'>
                
                <UserForm btnText="Add User" handleSubmitData={addUSer} />

                {users && users.map((user) => {
                    const { id, username,profileImage} = user;
                    return (
                        <div className='col-3 p-2' key={id}>
                            <img src={profileImage} alt="" className='profile_picture rounded-circle mx-auto' />
                            <h1>{username}</h1>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
        </section>
    )
}
export default Users;
```

***UserForm.js:***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const UserForm = ({ handleSubmitData, btnText }) => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        username: "",
        profileImage: "",
        email: "",
    });



    //handle change
    const HandleChange = (e) => {
        const SelectedFieled = e.target.name;
        const SelectedValue = e.target.value;
        setUser(prevState => {
            return { ...prevState, [SelectedFieled]: SelectedValue }
        })
    }

    const HandleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleSubmitData(user);
        setUser({
            username: "",
            profileImage: "",
            email: "",
        });
    }

    const { username, email, profileImage } = user;
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <form onSubmit={HandleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name='username'onChange={HandleChange} required value={username} />
                <input type="file" name='profileImage' onChange={HandleChange} value={profileImage} />
                <input type="email" name='email'onChange={HandleChange} required value={email} />
                <button>{btnText}</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserForm;
```

---

### Django Rest Api

***models.py:***

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, error_messages={"unique":"The email must be unique!"})
    profileImage = models.ImageField(null = True,blank = True,upload_to = "1_Profile-Picture")
    REQUIRES_FIELDS = ["email"]
    objects = CustomeUserManager()
```

***manager.py:***

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class CustomeUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username = username, email = email, password = password, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user  

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError("The super user must have staff=true")

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError("The super user must have is_superuser=true")

        return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

***serializer.py:***

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import User


class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            "username",
            "email",
            "profileImage",
        )

        extra_kwargs = {
           "password": {"write_only":True, "style":{"input_type": "password"}
           } 
        }

    def create(self, validate_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=validate_data['username'],
            email=validate_data['email'],
            profileImage=validate_data['profileImage'],
        )
        return user
```

***views.py:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import(
    User
)
from rest_framework import parsers,generics  
from .serializer import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    parser_classes = [parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser]
```

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: @krskara yes...